# Splitting a string which contains mathematical operators in python

Tags: python, string, list

world!, I ran into a problem earlier today... I am trying to split operations apart from digits and variables. it'll split `+`,`-`,`/`,`*` apart from the digits or the variable **(ex: 10+11+10 goes in the code and a list comes out with `["10","+","11","+","10"])`**

## My code:

```py
x = "100+20+a"

operators = ["*","/","+","-"]

def get_index_of(OP,txt):
  return [v for v,i in enumerate(txt+"+") if i == OP]

l = []
for i in operators:
  l.append(get_index_of(i,x))

spliting = sum(l,[])

out = []
for j in spliting:
  out.append(x)
  x = x[:j]

print(out)
```

## The output I get:

```
['100+20+a', '100', '100']
```

## The output I want:

```
["100","+","20","+","a"]
```

Comment: Can you use 3rd party lib - such as *more_itertools*?

Comment: Unless there's a specific requirement that this needs to be done using string splitting, I would rather use the "re" module to do some regex magic instead ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using stack

```
def parse(expression, operators = ["*","/","+","-"]):
    stack = ['']               # start with empty string on stack
    for c in expression:
        if c in operators:
            stack.append(c)    # place operator as new element on stack
            stack.append('')
        elif c != " ":         # not a space
            stack[-1] += c     # append to last element on stack
            
    return stack
```

**Example**

```
print(parse("100+20+a"))
# Output: ['100', '+', '20', '+', 'a']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
from itertools import groupby

x = "100+20+a"
operators = {"*", "/", "+", "-"}  # <-- use set instead of a list

out = ["".join(g) for _, g in groupby(x, operators.__contains__)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['100', '+', '20', '+', 'a']
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrej Kesely , but I was looking for raw python/ without external modules

Comment: @FahimFerdous [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html) is built-in module included in Python

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to 3rd party tool - there is a simple approach:

It's easy to convert to your desired *function*.

```py
from more_itertools import split_at

>>>lst = list(split_at(x, lambda x: x == '+', keep_separator=True))
                       
>>>lst
                       
[['1', '0', '0'], ['+'], ['2', '0'], ['+'], ['a']]
outs = [''.join(x) for x in lst]
                       
>>>outs
                       
['100', '+', '20', '+', 'a']

# or doing in one shot:
>>>final = [''.join(x) for x in split_at(x, lambda x: x == '+', keep_separator=True)]
```

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Hao for the help!, but I was looking for more of a raw/pure python way without external modules

Comment: NP.  It's great to know those nice powerful lib. sometimes it's very handy. *Stack* is good in this case, but you could make the req. clearer next time.

Answer (score 1):

Well after my first comment above, I took a break. I still decided to post this regex implementation:

```
import re

def split_using_regex(x='', ops='*/+-'):
    r = "([0-9A-Za-z]+).?([%s]{1})" % ops
    return [s.strip() for s in re.sub(r,r"\1,\2,",x).split(",")]


>>> split_using_regex('10 - 30 / 3 + 7* c+4')
['10', '-', '30', '/', '3', '+', '7', '*', 'c', '+', '4']

>>> split_using_regex('100+20-*a')
['100', '+', '20', '*', 'a']
```

Comment: You're very welcome :)
And I'm quite sure that the regex-way of doing this will outperform any for-loop. 
Personally, I would write this as an even more optimal oneliner, maybe lambda.

I turned this into a function and spread it out only for the same clarity for the people at the start of their python journeys :)